# E-bike battery: upgrade 18650 cells

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, batteries

I have an e-bike battery of capacity: 4.3Ah (Li-ion). Specifications: http://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf2/ACA4000/ACA4000CE285.pdf

For charging, the label on battery says "Rating 25.9V 4.05Ah 105Wh"
and charger output is DC+29.2V 2.0A

Due to its usage and age, I want to replace 18650 cells in it.
Most probably cell capacity is 2150mAh. Total 20 cells.

I wanted to know if I can upgrade the cell to something like Panasonic NCR18650B which is approx 3400mAh so that overall battery capacity will be increased. If it is possible, generally does this type of upgrade requires any circuit change in battery? Same charger ok?
NCR18650B specifications: http://na.industrial.panasonic.com/sites/default/pidsa/files/ncr18650b.pdf

Comment: The original cells may be low capacity because they are tuned for high current (fast charge and discharge). The higher capacity cells may not survive very long under the same use. Check the datasheets of both cell types very carefully... (Incidentally are you sure about the cell count? 10 cells in series would be about 36V nominal, unless they are a different chemistry (LiFePO4 32V, LTO about 24V). If the cell chemistry is different, same charger definitely NOT OK.

Comment: @Brian Drummond yes I am sure that cell count is 20-21. Probably all cells are not in series. If new cells are of type of same chemistry and same output voltage, just higher capacity, then is same charger ok?

Comment: 21 cells could be 3 strings of 7, note that 3.7V* 7 = 25.9V. Which would make the cells 1.35 Ah each. Is same charger OK? Still unlikely, unless it's a slow charger.

Comment: @Brian Drummond can you please tell me how how to identify if my charger is a slow charger? I have updated the question with battery specs and charger output info.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the original cells to compare datasheets, I believe your first order of priority would be to measure the de-facto charging mode of the charger and then try to estimate if the new cells are up to it - particularly by the charging current parameter (as pointed out in the comments), which happens to be about 1700mA in CC-CV 0.5C mode according to the Panasonic Datasheet.

Comment: I have updated the question with more info about batteries and charger

Answer (score 0):

If your charger is slow and limited to 4.2V, most likely it is compatible.

NCR specs: 0.5C max 4.20V 65mA cut-off at 25'C

Comment: I have updated the question with battery specs and charger info. Can you please tell me if it's safe?

Comment: The batteries are better but your charger is unknown but possibly if OK before then OK now but of course takes longer to charge and also discharge.